# Awk gsub and the mysterious "1"

Tags: awk, gsub

I think it is a more general understanding problem but here is my question:
If I run the following command in the terminal:

**awk '{gsub("a","H")}1'**

on the file marks.txt:

*1)      Amit    Physics 80

2)      Rahul   Maths   90

3)      Shyam   Biology 87

4)      Kedar   English 85

5)      Hari    History 89*

I get the following result:

*1)      Amit    Physics 80

2)      RHhul   MHths   90

3)      ShyHm   Biology 87

4)      KedHr   English 85

5)      HHri    History 89*

But if I run it without that "1", I get nothing.

**awk '{gsub("a","H")}'**

Why is this one so important and what does it stand for?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: See the "Learn more" page of the [tag:awk] tag page, the answer is right there.

Comment: Have a look at [awk one-liners explained](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/awk-one-liners-explained-part-one/) and look at the first example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Awk works on `condition { action }` expressions where the default action is `print $0`. When you write `1` as a condition then that is a true condition and so invokes the default action of printing the current record.