# replace lines having only one field with space/char

Tags: awk, sed

I want to do two things in a long table, for which an example block is given below.

(1) replace all lines having a single field (e.g. lines containing 102 and 103) with a character (e.g. the character I've used is "m")

(2) If there are m's in two consecutive lines (i.e., instead of 102 and 103, you will have an "m" in each line after above (1) ), then remove one of these lines so that

this would look like

```
-84.7363,   18.0227
-84.4994,   18.0632
-84.2222,   18.1732
102
103
 -84.4994,   18.0632
-84.2222,   18.1732
```

this after (1)

```
-84.7363,   18.0227
-84.4994,   18.0632
-84.2222,   18.1732
m
m
-84.4994,   18.0632
-84.2222,   18.1732
```

and this after (2)

```
-84.7363,   18.0227
-84.4994,   18.0632
-84.2222,   18.1732
m
-84.4994,   18.0632
-84.2222,   18.1732
```

Comment: It is not clear, could you please do add more clear details in your post and let us know then?

Comment: comments are NOT meant for information, please do update your post with proper details and let us know then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this awk-command:

```
awk -F"," '(NF==1){if(a){} else {print "m"; a=1}}(NF>1){a=0; print $0}' inputFileName
```

The `(NF==1)` condition checks whether the line has one field only. (This is where a replacement is necessary.)

The variable `a` equals `1` if the previous line has already been replaced.

Comment: This will fail if there are no entries on a line.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{ if (length($0) < 4) {print "Char";} else {print $0}}' filename | tr '\n' '\r' | sed -e 's,Char\rChar,bla,g' | tr '\r' '\n'
```

See if this works for you ?

1. filename is the input,
2. awk checks the length & prints accordingly
3. sed replaces two continuous Chars to Char

Comment: This will not work as `awk` is not having any input file and thus will take `/dev/stdin` as input. Furthermore, `$line` will never be substituted as it is enclosed in single quotes. Also, why would you use a `while`-loop if awk can just do that (awk is designed to read a file line by line). Otherwise, I have no comments. With a few fixes, this could work. (last note, if you want to use a while loop, use `while read -r line; do ...; done < /path/to/file`. Notice the `-r` to avoid backslash interpretations.

Comment: Please see this as constructive comments.

Comment: Your update will now work, but there is a **but**. You wrote `length($line)` while  `line` is not defined. So `awk` assumes that `line` has the value of zero, and thus `length($line)` is interpreted as `length($0)`. This is why it works, but it would be better to replace it. Otherwise thumbs up!

Comment: Now lets have a look at your pipeline (`... | tr '\n' '\r' | sed -e 's,Char\rChar,bla,' | tr '\r' '\n'`). You replace all `\n` with `\r` which I think is a very nice idea! But `sed` reads until the first `\n` or `EOF`. This means that `sed` reads the full file into memory. You might actually achieve the same by using the `-z` option of `sed` (but only for GNU sed, not POSIX sed). So you could replace the pipeline with `... | sed -z -e 's,Char\nChar,Char,g'` (also notice the `g` at the end of `sed`, something you are currently missing for multiple occurences).

Comment: So Since you wrote a POSIX implementation, I like it better!

Comment: sed: invalid option -- 'z'

Comment: Aha, so you do not have Gnu sed. As I said it is a gnu extension and not POSIX. You might be interested in Example 69 of [Sed One-liners explained](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-three/). This explains how you could mimic the GNU version with pure `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\S*$/{s//m/;n;//d}' file
```

If a line is blank or contains a single field, replace the current line with an `m` and then print that line and replenish the pattern space with the next line. If that line also is blank or contains a single field, delete it.

This solution caters for two successive such lines, if two or more, here are a couple more solutions:

```
sed -n '/^\S*$/{s//m/p;:a;n;//ba};p' file
```

Or:

```
sed '/^\S*$/!{x;z;x;b};x;s/^/m/;/^m$/p;x;d' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'NF==1{if (!p) print "m"; p=1; next} {print; p=0}' file
-84.7363,   18.0227
-84.4994,   18.0632
-84.2222,   18.1732
m
 -84.4994,   18.0632
-84.2222,   18.1732
```

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your question can be solved using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) as:

```
awk '(NF==1){print "m"; next}1'
```

Since [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) works with `(condition){action}` pairs, we understand the above as:

1. Check if there is only a single field, if so, print `m` and move to the next record/line.
2. If the above condition does not apply, we move to the next action which is `1`, a very short form for the pair `1{print $0}`. I.e. print the line. (See [Awk gsub and the mysterious "1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502311/awk-gsub-and-the-mysterious-1))

The second part of your question needs to keep track if previously we only had a single field. Let's keep track of it with a flag `f`

```
awk '(NF==1){ if (!f) print "m"; f=1; next}{f=0}1'
```

Assume that `f` is set to ONE if the previous line had a single field and otherwise ZERO (and know that at the start `f=0`), then we understand the above as:

1. Check if there is only a single field, if so, if the previous line had not a single field, print `m`. Then set `f=1` and move to the next line/record
2. If the previous action does not hold, set `f` to the value `0`
3. and print the line `1`.

In [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) you could do:

```
sed '$!N;s/\n[^,]*$/\nm/;/^[^,]*\n[^,]*$/!P;D'
```

Which does:

1. `$!N` if not at the EOF, append the next line to the pattern buffer
2. `s/\n[^,]*$/\nm/` replace the last line in the pattern buffer with a single letter `m` if it only contains a single field (I assume fields are comma separated)
3. `/^[^,]*\n[^,]*$/!P` If the pattern buffer contains two lines with only a single field, do not print the pattern buffer.
4. `D` delete everything upto the first `\n` in  the pattern buffer.

This is a small adaptation of Example 69 in [Sed one-liners explained](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-three/)

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -F, 'NF==1 {p=1; next} 
           p     {print "m"; p=0}1; 
           END   {if(p) print "m"}' file

-84.7363,   18.0227
-84.4994,   18.0632
-84.2222,   18.1732
m
 -84.4994,   18.0632
-84.2222,   18.1732
```

Answer (score 1):

Though Perl is not tagged, it works best for such scenarios. Try this.

```
$ cat januka.txt
-84.7363,   18.0227
-84.4994,   18.0632
-84.2222,   18.1732
102
103
 -84.4994,   18.0632
-84.2222,   18.1732
$ perl -0777 -pe ' s/^\S+$/m/mg; s/(^m\n){2,}/$1/mg ' januka.txt
-84.7363,   18.0227
-84.4994,   18.0632
-84.2222,   18.1732
m
 -84.4994,   18.0632
-84.2222,   18.1732
$
```

It can be even shortened as

```
$ perl -0777 -pe ' s/(^\S+\n){2,}/m\n/mg ' januka.txt
-84.7363,   18.0227
-84.4994,   18.0632
-84.2222,   18.1732
m
 -84.4994,   18.0632
-84.2222,   18.1732
$
```